# Cron Job Throwing error 500 internal server error

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

Cron job fails with Error 500 Internal Server Error
   I receive the following error

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=xxxxxxxx(I replaced the value); path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-
check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I have tried changing the cron.php file permissions to 744, 755, and 644 respectively but still does not work. I set up the cron with the command

```
/usr/bin/php /home/my_username/public_html/cron.php
```

- Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: This error message is response of the HTTP request, but `/usr/bin/php /home/my_username/public_html/cron.php` it is CLI command :|

Comment: The absolute first thing you do on a 500 Internal Server Error, is you _go check the server log files_ ...

Comment: @CBroe, the server log files are empty, I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: @Neodan, ur suggestion was very handy in solving the problem, thanks to you I changed my command to wget -O - my_domain.com/cron.php and everythihg now works very well.
Please answer the question so I can accept your answer. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is a response of the HTTP request, but `/usr/bin/php /home/my_username/public_html/cron.php` is the CLI command.

The problem can be in that your cron.php is not designed to work via CLI (try to run it via wget).

Comment: superb! turns out that wget solves the problem. Here's the command that now works
_wget -O - my_domain.com/cron.php_
I hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

Just add up your `openssl.conf` path to end of your command like this:

```
-config G:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.35\conf\openssl.cnf
```

This will help to generate your own certificate without errors. For linux the directory should be:

```
/usr/bin/apache{Version}/conf/openssl.cfg
```